# How can I properly resolve the configuration for my class path file dealing with Firebase and Android Studios?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I have been searching all morning on how to fix an error I have been having. “Could not find con.google.gms:google-service:4.3.15. I have the right names in firebase, that is the version firebase even told me to add to my build.gradle file.  Please help.

I have tried to change the version, create a whole new project, add a new firebase project. Nothing is working. I have gotten all the dependencies over and over.